# Dropping Always On Availability Group Owners

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I really tried to find info on this but all I could find was this doc: [Who owns your availability groups?](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/who-owns-your-availability-groups)

We have many Always On Availability Groups. All of them are owned by a past user not in a company anymore. Today I was planning to remove their login but I noticed this user is the owner of these Always On Availability Groups.

I'm not sure if just alter authorization would work here. In the link I provided it says it didn't help, and the only fix is to drop the Always On Availability Groups and recreate them.

Comment: By the sound of that article, it was only a problem if they used `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` *after* dropping the login. What happens if you try before, does it work?

Comment: I didnt actually tried yet since its a prod isue but I'm going to do a lab on Monday on it